# Copy data from spreadsheet into Array for filtering

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the following code in a macro that I wrote:

```
Columns("B:E").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$E$1000000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("90", "95"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Selection.Copy
Set WS = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("ID Sheet"), Type:=xlWorksheet)
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("B:E").Select
Columns("B:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveSheet.Name = "Deals"
```

Its purpose is to filter the data, and copy it to a different spreadsheet. It works well for its purpose, but as the codes in the array are hardcoded, it is time consuming to change.

I am wondering is there any way to get data from a location in another spreadsheet to be entered in the array automatically?

IE:

```
Columns("B:E").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$E$1000000").AutoFilter Field:=3, _
Criteria1:=Array(***CODE IN HERE TO REFER to RANGE IN SHEET 2***), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
Selection.Copy
Set WS = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("ID Sheet"), Type:=xlWorksheet)
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("B:E").Select
Columns("B:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveSheet.Name = "Deals"
```

EDIT:

To provide some more clarity.

The list of values I am looking to enter into the array is 3k+. The list is imported from a different program, and stored in a specific location in Sheet2. Every time a user runs the program, the list of values imported will change, as will the number (range is from 300 - 30k). They will always be imported into the same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a form with a textbox that allows the user to enter the codes for the array separated by commas, then use the split function to populate your array. eg

```
Dim arrCriteria as Variant
UserForm1.show vbModal
arrCriteria = Split(UserForm1.Textbox1.Text, ",")
Unload UserForm1
Criteria1:=arrCriteria
```

On the Userform you just need your textbox and an Ok button. The Ok button should just hide userform1. If you unload it before you get the value of the textbox, the values entered into the textbox will be lost.

---

Based on your comment, the elements of the array that are used as filter criteria get placed on another sheet. Assuming they are all on the same row, simply load your array by looping through the columns or rows. eg:

```
Dim arrCriteria() as Variant '(or String or Long or whatever your data type is)
Dim intArrLen as Integer
Dim c as Integer
intArrLen = Sheet2.UsedRanged.Columns.Count
'If your array criteria get placed in a column instead of a row use:
'intArrLen = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'And then update the code 5 line below to:
'    arrCriteria(c) = Sheet2.Cells(c, 1).Value
ReDim arrCriteria (1 to intArrLen)
For c = 1 to intArrLen
    'Presuming the array criteria get loaded to row 1
    arrCriteria(c) = Sheet2.Cells(1, c).Value
Next c
```

It seems your issue is manually editing your macro to contain all the elements in your array that you use to filter the data on your sheet. You haven't given the best description of where the criteria comes from (apparently it comes from another sheet) nor did you mention how much there was (your example code had 2 elements in your array but in your comment you state there are thousands of elements). Both code examples show you different methods of loading an array. Play around with them to come up with the best method that works for you. If you still get stuck, update your question with the code that is failing and someone on SO will happily help. :)

Comment: While that is a good idea, the number of items in the array tops 3k. Also, the list is imported from an external program, which puts the items in Sheet 2 of the workbook.